# Automorphisms in Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

1. Let $G$ be a group, and $H$ a subgroup of G, and f in $Aut(G)$. Prove that $[G:H]=[G:f(H)]$.
2. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $f$ in $Aut(G)$, prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $G/f(N)$.

My ideas so far are the following:

For 1. consider $f|_H: H \rightarrow f(H)$. This is a bijection, so $\# N = \# f(N)$. Hence by Lagrange's Theorem $[G:H] = \frac{\#G}{\#N} = \frac{\#G}{\#f(N)}  = [G:f(H)]$.

For 2. Define the homomorphism $h: G \rightarrow G/f(N) : g \mapsto gf(N)$. Then $a \in Ker(f) \Leftrightarrow h(a) = f(N) \Leftrightarrow af(N) = f(N) \Leftrightarrow a \in N$. Then by the isomoprhism theorem we have that $G/N \cong G/f(N)$.

Does anyone know in how far it is correct what I have now? The troubling thing for 2. is that I'm not using the assumption that $N$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: why is $G/N$ a group??  It is precisely because N is normal!!

Comment: Also your calculation with the kernel is not right..  The map that you have taken is the canonical map which has $f(N)$ as its kernel and not $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $f(N)=K$. Since f is an automorphism it maps a normal subgroup to a normal subgroup. Hence K is normal. Actually any surjective group homomorphism maps a normal subgroup to a normal subgroup.

Define the map $h:G \to G/K$ as h(g)=f(g)K

Observe that the map is well defined. It is a group homomorphism. And now Check its kernel.You will get $Ker(h)=N$, then by first isomorphism theorem $G/N \cong G/K$

Comment: Great, thanks !